# No module found 'corsheaders' django/heroku deploy

Tags: python, django, cors, django-cors-headers

None of the other answers have worked for me. Ive done `pipenv install django-cors-headers`, `pipenv install psycopg2-binary`, etc. until my fingers have blisters to no avail...

This is going to be a bit long if you don't mind looking; thanks in advance...

```
*settings.py*

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'quizzes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
] 


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

This is the Pipfile on the proper level...

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"

[packages]
python-decouple = "*"
"psycopg2" = "*"
django-dotenv = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
whitenoise = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
django = "*"
django-cors-headers = "*"
"psycopg2-binary" = "*"

[dev-packages]
```

But I am still getting traceback `line 17` from ./manage.py and ultimately No module named 'corsheaders'...  I've uninstalled/reinstalled and everything. Anyone got any ideas?

- edit: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you find an answer in the end? I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I noticed that I forgot to add this:

```
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
```

to my requirements.txt

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue - try installing `django-cors-headers` with pip3/pip/pipenv. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: Suggestions that are not clear answers should be posted as a comment